# Изменить папку python

Tags: python

Такой вопрос, как изменить папку сохранения в

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, str(id) +'.jpg')
```

Мне нужно чтобы все сохранялось в /img/, а не рядом со скриптом.
Спасибо

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 2):

Просто указать папку вместе с именем файла:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/img/' + str(id) +'.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/images/'))
```

Сменит рабочий каталог на /home/username/images.

os.chdir('img')

Сменит каталог на img рядом со скриптом.